# gRPC with HTTP+JSON Gateway

Tags: reverse-proxy, grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy, grpc-gateway

I am trying to build a gRPC service in Java. I also want to serve HTTP+JSON requests. I read about Envoy and grpc-gateway for creating a reverse proxy. But I am not able to do so effectively. I have added google.api.http option in proto file but I am stuck here.
Can anyone tell how to go about this problem with some steps? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway you are using? Have you searched there for help?

Comment: I have tried it but I wasn't able to run it as my service was in java and I am not acquainted with go. But I have achieved what I was looking for with the help of Envoy. Thank You.